# Magento 2.3 create order programmatically

Tags: magento2

I am creating order programmatically in Magento 2.3.3

```
foreach ($orderData['items'] as $item) {
    $product = $this->_productFactory->create()->load($item['product_id']);
    $product->setPrice($item['custom_price']);
    $product->setStatus(1);
    $product->setIsInStock(true);
    $product->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 0, //'Use config settings' checkbox
            'min_sale_qty' => 1, //Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart
            'is_in_stock' => 1, //Stock Availability
        ));

    //To fix min sale qty different issue
    $productStockObj = $this->stockRegistryInterface->getStockItem($product->getId());
    $productStockObj->setData('min_sale_qty', 1);
    $productStockObj->setData('use_config_manage_stock', 1);
    $productStockObj->setData('use_config_min_sale_qty', 1);

    $quote->addProduct(
        $product, intval($item['qty'])
    );
}
```

I am creating an order for `Disabled` and `Out of Stock` products.

This code was working fine before in Magento 2.2 but now I'm getting an error like **`This product is out of stock.`** when product is `Disabled` or `Out of Stock` in the admin.

I have also changed the Admin setting as below.

```
Catalog > Inventory > Stock Options > Decrease Stock When Order is Placed = No
Inventory > Product Stock Options > Manage stock = No
Inventory > Product Stock Options > Backorders = Allow QTY below 0
```

Comment: Save the product before adding it quote and load it again

Comment: I don't want to change real product qty. So saving product is not the real solution :(

Comment: I'm not sure, but from Magento 2.3.x, Magento will use the Multi inventory logic. It can cause your issue.